# Using @fontface with DigitalOcean Spaces

Tags: django, django-templates, digital-ocean

I've started learning to use django and have starting working on hosting one on Digital Ocean's App platform.
I'm hosting my static files on Digital Ocean's Spaces. My CSS file loads just fine. My fonts, however, do not.

My file structure is as folows:

```
Project
--Static
---CSS
    -CSS files
---Fonts
    - font files
```

I set up my @font-face in the CSS file like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'poppins';
    src: url('../static/fonts/Poppins-Light.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```

and apply the font as follows:

```
.div-name{
    height: 100px;
    font-family: 'poppins';
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

Like I said, my CSS loads just fine, the fonts are just not showing up.
What am i missing?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`url('../static` means go up one folder from the file, then into /static, so UP from *inside* /css to *inside* /static and then DOWN into /static

However up there is no /static folder *inside* static, you have miscalculated your folder levels.

To fix you can use an absolute url `url('/static/...` or make your relative url work correctly `url(../fonts`

**Absolute URL:** if `url('/` begins with a slash, it means it starts that the root of the site and works down. You can test absolute URLs by typing them in your browser, eg go to http://127.0.01:8000/static/fonts/Poppins-Light.woff2 and see if it downloads the file

**Relative url:** means it starts with the file and moves relative to it.  Your example starts with your .css file in /css, then goes up via `../` into the /static folder. /static has both /CSS and /Fonts folders inside it so the full url is `url('../Fonts/Poppins-Light.woff2')`.  You don't need to mention /static as you stay inside it the whole time.  If you used `url('../../`, eg, up *two* levels, then you would need to mention /static.

Comment: But if I do "/static/...." how does the CSS file know where to look? 
What do you mean by make the relative URl work correctly?

Comment: I've added some extra explanation of the difference between static and relative